# Is "there" a dummy subject in "There seems to be a lot of heat in here"?

Tags: existentials

I would like an explanation of the difference between the two following structures as to the type of subjects that they have:

> 1. "**It** seems hot in here."
> 2. "**There** seems to be a lot of heat in here."

In my opinion, in the first structure (#1) there is a subject ("it"), whereas in the second structure (#2) we use "there" as a dummy subject.

Am I right?

Comment: In your first example, the "there" is probably the dummy pronoun subject of an existential due to the use of "here" as a locative expression.

Comment: "It seems to be hot." "There seems to be a lot of heat."

Comment: @Vic You should [edit] your question to include those examples, so that people will seem them more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Both the *it* in (1) and the *there* in (2) are dummies; that is, they don't refer to anything,
and they're present in the sentence only to fill the subject slot.

- the *it* in (1) is "[Ambient *it*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/95947/15299)", a dummy *it* for deictic time and place
    ***It's*** hot ~ **It's** noon ~ **It** will be too late then ~ **It's** raining.
  Other dummy *it* types include ["Distance" *it*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/73821/15299), and the *it* inserted by rule in *It*-[Cleft](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20cleft) sentences:
    *Bill ordered salmon ~ **It** was Bill that ordered salmon ~  **It** was salmon that Bill ordered.*
- the *there* in (2) is the existential dummy *there* inserted by the rule called [*There*-Insertion](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/190345/15299ou).
    (examples in link)

So they're both dummies, of different sorts. As to whether they are subjects, ...

- Subjects agree with verbs. Even when it's a dummy, *it* is still a third person singular pronoun.
    *It is raining* is grammatical, but not **It are raining* or **It am raining*.
  So dummy *it* -- of all types -- can be a subject. (There are also dummy *it* objects.)
- Dummy *there* is a subject by some tests, and not (yet) by others.
  For one thing, *there* isn't a noun, so it can't be either singular or plural.
  Agreement with verbs in [the list governing *There*-Insertion](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/thereins.vbs.html) is officially
  supposed to be with the displaced original subject, which can be singular or plural
    *There **is** a man here to see you* ~ *There **are** some people here to see you.*
  although contraction (and the difficulty of contracting *there are*) makes singular a default
    ***There's*** a man here to see you ~ **There's** some people here to see you
  There are [other tests](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/200676/15299). But this is already too long.

Let it stand that one can consider dummy *there* to be the subject; or one can consider the displaced noun phrase after the verb to be the subject. Each is correct, for some value of "Subject".

Comment: Is it a "subject" (standing in for ***you***) if Mummy exclaims ***There's** a good boy!* when he uses a potty for the first time? I sometimes think ***Oo's** a good boy!* could be either ***Who is...*** or ***You is...*** according to how you feel at the time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, unless you don’t know who is performing an action, or you want to emphasize the action of the sentence for some reason, you should avoid dummy subjects. When we use the words it and there to begin a sentence without a referent (a noun the pronoun is referring to), we’re using a dummy subject.
That would make them both have dummy subjects.